# Set maximum size for JavaFX ImageView

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

I resize the image view according to the scene but image keep resizing even if the scene is bigger than image original size.

I have set `ImageView.maxWidth(originalImageWidth)` but it did not work.

I resize the ImageView by binding it's size to the the scene size.

Comment: i do the same and its working fine..i think instead of using stage use parent pane of image view like anchor pane

Comment: @AnshulParashar I'm using stackpane as parent parent for image view and it did not work.

Answer (score 3):

This would work

```
Pane root = new VBox(); //or other Pane sub-class
ImageView bg = new ImageView(...);
bg.setPreserveRatio(false);
bg.fitWidthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty());
bg.fitHeightProperty().bind(root.heightProperty());
root.getChildren().addAll(bg);
```

Answer (score 0):

May not be too relevant anymore but i found a solution that works for me at least:

- set setPreserveRatio to true,
- set fitHeight to the wanted maximum width * ratio
- bind the fitWidthProperty to the screnes widthProperty

In other words: you can bind one dimension and have a maximum fit size to the other at the same time.