# JavaFX: maximum ImageView size

Tags: javafx

This may sound like a duplicate of [Set maximum size for JavaFX ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501090/set-maximum-size-for-javafx-imageview) but it's different.

I'd like to restrict the maximum size of an ImageView. Unfortunately, the only way to set the ImageView's size seems to be fitWidth and fitHeight which however enlarges the image if it's smaller than the fit values.

I tried setting fitWidth/fitHeight to 0/0 and wrap the ImageView into a pane with maxWidth set - no success (image is displayed in original size).

To me it seems as this is not achievable by JavaFX, however I can't believe it. But I couldn't find anything online. Are there any tricks/bugs/workarounds on this?

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want the image to stretch, you can use:

```
setPreserveRatio(true);
```

Then you are able to fit width and height as you want
[ImageView setPreserveRatio javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#setPreserveRatio(boolean))

---

In javadoc in this method there are the rules of scaling too

Comment: I should've used "enlarge" instead of "stretch". Setting one of the fit properties causes any image smaller than that to be enlarged. I want to keep the original image size if it's smaller but restrict its maximum length.

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to add in if statement to set those larger than maxsize to a fixed size. The rest would remain their original size.

```
        ImageView im = new ImageView();
        im.setImage(image);
        im.maxHeight(690 - 10);   
        int yoursize = 690; 
        if(im.maxHeight(690 - 10)> yoursize ){
           im.setFitHeight(690- 10);  
           System.out.println("Fix Size : 690 ");
        }
        im.setPreserveRatio(true);
        im.setSmooth(true);
        im.setCache(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the actual Image resource and query its width/height to use for the fit values:

```
  Image image = imageView.getImage();

  double nativeWidth = image.getWidth();
  double nativeHeight = image.getHeight();
```